# Not a piecewise function with a "ceiling".

Tags: functions

There is a function $$f(n,i,m) =i-1+m$$ Where m and n are actually constants and are set separately each time, and i changes its value from 1 to n inclusive, but when the value of the function becomes greater than n, it must take a value equal to n.

This can be done by making the function piecewise, but I don't like this solution and I'm wondering if it's possible to implement it in any other way?

Comment: $\min(i-1+m,n).$

Comment: "Piecewise" does not mean anything in math. If you don't like your function to be defined via a big curly brace and some explicit "if...then...else" condition, write it in any other way without those.